# How to store np arrays into psql database and django

Tags: python, numpy, psql

I develop an application that will be used for running simulation and optimization over graphs (for instance Travelling salesman problem or various other problems).

Currently I use 2d numpy array as graph representation and always store list of lists and after every load/dump from/into DB I use function `np.fromlist`, `np.tolist()` functions respectively.

Is there supported way how could I store numpy ndarray into psql? Unfortunately, np arrays are not JSON-serializable by default.

I also thought to convert numpy array into scipy.sparse matrix, but they are not json serializable either

Answer (score 2):

json.dumps(np_array.tolist()) is the way to convert a numpy array to json. np_array.fromlist(json.loads(json.dumps(np_array.tolist()))) is how you get it back.

Comment: your answer is basically the same what I wrote my current workflow.

Comment: At the risk of loosing precision for floats